# Why my Input touch code doesn't work on AR Foundation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, touch, augmented-reality

Trying to build an AR app where I can have a number of input touch like drag, rotate, scale, double tap to event, hold on object to event etc. 
Everything works fine in a test scene I have built [not AR]. 
Once included the code in my AR placedOnPlane prefab [template scene - place on plane], once I touch the object, it disappears, and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong!

Finally, I took advantage of LeanTouch and everything works fine (why? because it's a badass asset), but I usually hate using assets when I have my code that is working equally good and I spent days on it! Some help please.

I tried commenting out the built in drag function in the PlacedOnPlane code that comes with the scene of ARfoundation but it didn't work.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.iOS;

public class InputTouchUnity : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 position;
    private float width;
    private float height;
    public float speedDrag= 0.1f;
    float initialFingersDistance;
    float speedTwist = -4000f;
    private float baseAngle = 0.0f;
    Vector3 initialScale;

 // scale clamp

     //public float scalingSpeed = 0.03f;
     public Vector3 min = new Vector3(292f, 292f, 292f);
     public Vector3 max = new Vector3(800f, 800f, 800f);

    // int tapCount;
    // float doubleTapTimer;

    void Awake()
    {
        width = (float)Screen.width / 2.0f;
        height = (float)Screen.height / 2.0f;

        //Position used for the cube.
        position = this.transform.position;
    }

    void OnGUI() // TO OBSERVE MOTION
    {
        // Compute a fontSize based on the size of the screen width.
        GUI.skin.label.fontSize = (int)(Screen.width / 25.0f);

        GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 20, width, height * 0.25f),
            "x = " + position.x.ToString("f2") +
            ", y = " + position.z.ToString("f2"));
    }
    void Update()
    {



        // Handle screen touches.
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))

            initialScale = transform.localScale;

            {

                {

                    {
                         //DRAG - got rid of it because conflicting the AR drag
                            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
                          Move the cube if the screen has the finger moving.
                          if (Input.touchCount == 2)
                         {

                           if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                          {
                              Vector2 pos = touch.position;
                              pos.x = (pos.x - width) / width;
                              pos.y = (pos.y - height) / height;
                              position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + pos.x * speedDrag, 0, transform.position.y + pos.y * speedDrag);
                              // Position the cube.
                             transform.position = position;
                          }
                        }

                        //SCALE
                         if (Input.touchCount == 2)
                         {
                             Touch touch1 = Input.GetTouch(0);

                             if (touch1.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                             {
                                 initialFingersDistance = Vector2.Distance(Input.touches[0].position , Input.touches[1].position);
                                 initialScale = transform.localScale;
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 var currentFingersDistance = Vector2.Distance(Input.touches[0].position, Input.touches[1].position);
                                var scaleFactor = (currentFingersDistance  / initialFingersDistance );
                                 transform.localScale = initialScale * scaleFactor;
                                 Debug.Log(transform.localScale);

                                 GameObject[] models = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("ARobject");
                                   newScale.x = Mathf.Clamp(model.localScale.x - scaleFactor, min.x, max.x);
                                newScale.y = Mathf.Clamp(model.localScale.y - scaleFactor, min.y, max.y);
                                  newScale.z = Mathf.Clamp(model.localScale.z - scaleFactor, min.z, max.z);
                                   model.localScale = newScale;

                           }
                         }
                        //TWIST

                        if (Input.touchCount == 2)
                        {
                            Touch touch2 = Input.GetTouch(0);

                            if (touch2.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                            {
                                Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
                                pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
                                baseAngle = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
                                baseAngle -= Mathf.Atan2(transform.right.y, transform.right.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                            }
                            if (touch2.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                            {
                                Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
                                pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
                                float ang = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Deg2Rad - baseAngle;
                                transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ang * speedTwist, Vector3.up);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
//}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using Physics.Raycast which does't work on AR trackables(Planes) because they don't have any specific geometry associated with them. 
So to interact with trackable data unity has provided separate Raycast method that is available in ARRaycastManager in ARFoundation.
In previous version of ARFoundation it was available in ARSessionOrigin. So check which version you are using of Ar Foundation.
You can use it like this

enter code here

`

```
[SerializeField] ARRaycast​Manager raycastManager;
    void Update()
        {
             if (Input.touchCount == 0)
                return;
           Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

           if (raycastManager.Raycast(touch.position,s_Hits,TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon))
            {
                // Raycast hits are sorted by distance, so the first one
                // will be the closest hit.
                var hitPose = s_Hits[0].pose;
                if (spawnedObject == null)
                {
                    spawnedObject = Instantiate(cube, hitPose.position, hitPose.rotation);
                }
                else
                {
                    spawnedObject.transform.position = hitPose.position;
                }
            }
        }
```

`

You can also refer to SimpleAR scene from Ar Foundation sample scenes available here: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples